# ReferenceError: "goog" is not defined when running lein cljsbuild

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

I'm getting started with clojurescript and have added lein-cljsbuild to my project.clj:

```
(defproject hello-world "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-1450"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.3"]]
  :cljsbuild {:builds []})
```

When I run the following command in PowerShell and the command window:

```
lein trampoline cljsbuild repl-rhino
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
(Retrieving cljsbuild/cljsbuild/0.2.7/cljsbuild-0.2.7.jar from clojars)
Exception in thread "main" org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "goog" is not defined. (bootjs#1), 
compiling:(C:\Users\Karthik\AppData\Local\Temp\form-init8943880809592678534.clj:1:127)
```

What else do I need to do? The above steps were outlined in the book *ClojureScript: Up and Running* but for lein-cljsbuild "0.2.7"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following versions work for me:

```
(defproject hello-world "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write this!"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2173"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.2"]]

  :cljsbuild { 
    :builds []})
```

Updating to `lein-cljsbuild 1.0.3` and `clojurescript 0.0-2197` seems to break the rhino repl.

Comment: Thanks. Any reference to what's going on in the cljs toolchain here?

Comment: @tetotechy I think the relevant issue is [CLJS-790](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-790).  `lein-cljsbuild 1.0.3` works if you update to `clojurescript 0.0-2234` (optionally `clojure 1.6.0`)

Comment: @tetotechy -- correction: move to `clojure 1.6.0` and `clojurescript 0.0-2234` if you can, otherwise wait for an update on CLJS-790.

Comment: @Inmx - thanks, even if it does not seem to work with clojure 1.6.0 + cljs0.0-2234 either, unless you use the workaround in CLJS-790 (i.e. resorting to the old closure library in the project's project.clj)